# jQuery to replace content of a div with data stored in various variables dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this is my HTML. By default `container` shows some sample text. I want to replace it with corresponding HTML content stored in javascript variables.

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="link" id="item01">Menu 1</span></li>
  <li><span class="link" id="item02">Menu 2</span></li>
  <li><span class="link" id="item03">Menu 3</span></li>
  <li><span class="link" id="item04">Menu 4</span></li>
  <li><span class="link" id="item05">Menu 5</span></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">Sample Text</div>
```

Now HTML content is stored in variable `item01`, `item02`, `item03` and so on. So this is the jQuery I created.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var item01 = '<span>Content of item 1</span>';
    var item02 = '<span>Content of item 2</span>';
    var item03 = '<span>Content of item 3</span>';
    var item04 = '<span>Content of item 4</span>';
    var item05 = '<span>Content of item 5</span>';

    $('.link').on('click',function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       $itemNum = $this.attr("id");
       $('.container').html( $itemNum );
    });
  });
  //-->
</script>
```

But it's not working exactly as I want. It prints ID of the element in div `container` instead of HTML stored in that particular variable.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you store the HTML in an object so you can access it by key:

```
var content = {
    item01: '<span>Content of item 1</span>',
    item02: '<span>Content of item 2</span>',
    item03: '<span>Content of item 3</span>',
    item04: '<span>Content of item 4</span>',
    item05: '<span>Content of item 5</span>'
}

$('.link').on('click',function(){
   $('.container').html(content[this.id]);
});
```

Comment: Definitely the best answer

Comment: Perfect. Yes, it's working. Thank you. But why was not my solution working? Can't I simply replace something in my `$('.container').html( $itemNum );` to get the value from variable instead of printing it's name. Just want to know.

Comment: In your original the `$itemNum` variable was just an integer. You cannot retrieve a variable using the value of another variable unless you use something like `eval()`, which is exceptionally bad practice.

Comment: Thanks Rory for explanation. I already spent 2 hours on this problem and with this, you saved my another 4-5 hours. You are awesome. :)

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are getting the id attribute value. You should rather get the value of variable using `eval(varname)`:

```
$('.link').on('click',function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $itemNum = $this.attr('id');
   $('.container').html(eval($itemNum));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8957vg3p/)**

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the problem. OP is trying to show the content of the HTML in the `item01`, `item02` etc variables, not show a number.

Comment: Your code is working now. Thanks for your super fast help. I wish I could select 2 answers. Up voted you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the value of the variable $itemNum to the html()-function of the container. This variable contains the id of the clicked element.

Try saving your html-pieces in a named array instead:

```
var htmlArray = new Array();
htmlArray["item01"] = '<span>Content of item 1</span>';
htmlArray["item02"] = '<span>Content of item 2</span>';
```

Then get the piece of html by accessing the array with your id:

```
$('.link').on('click',function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   var id = $this.attr("id");
   $('.container').html( htmlArray[id] );
});
```

But keep in mind that holding parts of your html markup in js-variables is not a good practice. This may be a hint on a bad overall architecture.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tjb7bvmc/

Comment: Arrays cannot contain keys, I think you mean `Object()`.

Comment: There are named arrays in js. See the link I added on my answer.